# Is it possible to print only user defined variables by NM?

Tags: c++, mingw, nm

There are a lot of system variables in output of nm it looks like this

```
N
_CRT_MT
_CRT_fmode
_CRT_glob
Dictionary::variable4
namespace1::variable1
__cpu_features
__crt_xc_end__
__crt_xc_start__
__crt_xi_end__
__crt_xi_start__
__crt_xl_start__
__crt_xp_end__
__crt_xp_start__
__crt_xt_end__
__crt_xt_start__
__tls_end__
__tls_start__
__xl_a
__xl_c
__xl_d
__xl_z
_argc
_argv
_bss_end__
_bss_start__
_data_end__
_data_start__
_end__
_fmode
_tls_end
_tls_index
_tls_start
_tls_used
mingw_initltsdrot_force
mingw_initltsdyn_force
mingw_initltssuo_force
variable0
variable10
```

Is it possible to print only user defined variables - in this case variable10, variable0, Dictionary::variable1, Dictionary::variable4, N?

Comment: @DeadMG [`nm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I know of. But at least you can safely filter all variables starting with double underscore or underscore + uppercase letter, as these are reserved for the implementation:

```
$ nm -j foo | grep -v '^_[A-Z]\|^__\+[A-Za-z]'
N
Dictionary::variable4
namespace1::variable1
_argc
_argv
_bss_end__
_bss_start__
_data_end__
_data_start__
_end__
_fmode
_tls_end
_tls_index
_tls_start
_tls_used
mingw_initltsdrot_force
mingw_initltsdyn_force
mingw_initltssuo_force
variable0
variable10
```

You can probably filter more by adding additional patterns that reliably denote implementation-defined identifiers.

Alternatively, create an empty executable (i.e. one which contains *no* user-defined symbols) and compute the difference of the output of `nm` on each executable via [`comm`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comm):

```
$ # Preparation
$ echo 'int main() { }' > mt.cpp
$ g++ -o mt.out mt.cpp
$ nm -j mt.out > mt.symbols
$ 
$ nm -j your_exe > your_exe.symbols
$ comm -23 your_exe.symbols mt.symbols
N
Dictionary::variable4
namespace1::variable1
variable0
variable10
```

Comment: I can't perform additional filtering cuz this system variable names are unpredictable.

Comment: @Alex Well, look at my second method, it actually works quite well. Wait, let me show a more complete example.

Comment: Thanks, i will check it. But i work under windows 7, is there any analogues of comm?

Comment: @Alex I have no idea. But since you’re using `nm`, mustn’t you be using cygwin anyway? The lack of proper combinable tools is the reason I ditched Windows as a developer platform. It’s just not powerful enough.

Comment: Ok, anyway, i can do this work manually using matlab script. But i have a doubt - maybe if .cpp files will contain some additional details (rather than just void main{}) that will provoke occuring of new system variables.

Comment: @Alex Beware that `void main` is invalid C++. And yes, this method has limitations; like I said, I don’t think there’s a general method.

Comment: This solution is incomplete cuz new system symbols appearing : (